# How to iterate over a Set in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do you iterate over a set in TypeScript?  for..of does not work:

```
'Set<string>' is not an array type or a string type
```

`.forEach` is not acceptable, because it hides `this`. I'd prefer not to do a while loop in a try catch block. What am I missing? It can't it possibly so clumsy as to require try {while} catch {}.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

@SnareChops was mostly correct:

```
mySet.forEach(function(item){
    // do something with "this"
}, **this**);
```

This works.

I'm guessing:

```
for(item of mySet.values()){
}
```

Would work if I weren't working with es-shim stuff which is messing everything up for me.  But the shim stuff is prescribed by the Angular 2 crew so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The only other thing that worked was:

```
for (var item of Array.from(set.values())) {
}
```

or something like that, which is just terrible.

Comment: maybe you mean `Array.from()`

Answer (score 4):

Extending the most upvoted answer, it is also type-safe if we use `let` for the iteration variable, so:

```
for (let elem of setOfElems) {
   ... do anything with elem...
}
```

This will guarantee that `elem` will have the type X, if `setOfElems` was declared as `Set<X>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `.forEach` with the correct `this` by using a regular function instead of an arrow function

```
mySet.forEach(function(item){
    expect(this).toEqual(item);
});
```

Compared to

```
class MyClass{
    ...
    doSomething():{
        mySet.forEach((item) => {
            expect(this instanceof MyClass).toEqual(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Another way to iterate is to use a for loop over the values

```
for(item of mySet.values()){
    ...
}
```

More information on iterating `Set` with foreach can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach)

Comment: I appreciate the quick response but I've found the following to be true:

Approach 1:
"this" is not preserved, and i think it would normally be that lambda's are the ones to preserve "this"

Approach 2:
This doesn't compile for me.


The only way I've found that works so far aside from the "while" approach has been:
for (var key of Array.from(this.keys.values()))
and that's far from desirable since I think it creates a new array and Array.from isn't fully supported everywhere.

Comment: The follwing __ to be true?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for ... of` in TypeScript if you add `"es6"` as `"lib"` in your compiler options, and `"es6"` as target. You may also use `"es2015.iterable"` in place of `"es6"` in your lib if that better suits your needs.

For example (this would be your tsconfig.json):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12707