# Typescript loop through a Set of values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following weird issue on my code using Typescript 2.6. I 'm trying to loop through a Set of string values but I get the following error and I don't understand why.

> 'Type 'Set' is not an array type or a string type. '

Here is what I have:

```
loopThroughSet(): void {

        let fruitSet = new Set()
        .add('APPLE')
        .add('ORANGE')
        .add('MANGO');

        for (let fruit of fruitSet) {
            console.log(fruit);
        }
}
```

Does anyone knows what's the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193471/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-in-typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a Set in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193471/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-in-typescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set are not define in TS, you need to configure TS with es2017.object or convert Set values to array :

```
for (var item of Array.from(fruitSet.values())) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo...that works.Thanks all of the responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fruitSet.forEach( fruit => ... )`

If you want to use `for..of`, try spread operator: `for (const fruit of [...fruitsSet]) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to iterate through a range of seven items without *defining* and *using* a variable that would be marked as [unused by ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars), and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) helped a lot.

```js
[...Array(7)].map(() => {
    // some code
});
```

instead of

```js
for (const _ of range(0, 7)) {
    // Some code
}
```