# How can i access a [set object} in a map in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my app i am using a 3 party Library returns the map like this

`public sids: Map<SocketId, Set<Room>> = new Map();`

and when i access it like this

```
io.of("/").adapter.sids.forEach(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + ' = ' + value)
})
```

the output looks like this..

```
qZq18yG3TkoBPXNTAAAC = [object Set] 
84q_yQYKB7JjOPAIAAAD = [object Set]
```

and when i log the whole map i get this..

```
Map(2) {
  'qZq18yG3TkoBPXNTAAAC' => Set(2) { 'qZq18yG3TkoBPXNTAAAC', 'demo' },
  '84q_yQYKB7JjOPAIAAAD' => Set(2) { '84q_yQYKB7JjOPAIAAAD', 'demo' }
}
```

so my question is how do i access the values in the [object Set] ? i tried via JSON.stringify but that doesn't return anything.

When using the suggested code like this..

```
  io.of("/").adapter.sids.forEach((set,key)=> {
        let demo = [...set]
        console.log('Key:', key,' Set to array: ', [...set] , set);
    });
```

i get the following unexpected

> Key: UJ3HwAIsHTgE9qvrAAAB  Set to array:  [] Set(2) {
> 'UJ3HwAIsHTgE9qvrAAAB', 'demo' } Key: Kvlt-mtnrE5NxMykAAAD  Set to
> array:  [] Set(2) { 'Kvlt-mtnrE5NxMykAAAD', 'demo' }

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193471/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-in-typescript

Comment: the Set object is an array that removes all duplicated values. If you want to print these values you should print the value.values(). More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 2):

You can spread a Set into an array if that helps

```js
const map =new Map([
  ['qZq18yG3TkoBPXNTAAAC', new Set(['qZq18yG3TkoBPXNTAAAC','demo'])],
  ['84q_yQYKB7JjOPAIAAAD', new Set(['84q_yQYKB7JjOPAIAAAD','demo'])]
])

map.forEach((set,key)=> {
  console.log('Key:', key,' Set to array: ', [...set]);
  console.log('Set has value "demo" =', set.has('demo'))
});
```

Comment: Thanks that looks pretty good, but i hve one more question, why doe my code print Set(2)  when there is 2 items in the object but in your sample its just a plain Set ? Just want to make sure i understand

Comment: It's just how the console is handling a Set object. It's telling you it is  a Set with two entries

Comment: Ok, just making sure i don't overlook something. In your sample you used the set.has, i tried that with key but got the error key.has is not a function. Final one would be can i apply a filter to the map.for each so it would only return the set where a key = a provided value ?

Comment: The key isn't the Set, the value is

Comment: Ok, so it seems i can filter on keys directly ? i tried your code in my app but it does not produce the expected output. i have added code and result to my original question

Answer (score 0):

Look at the element definition `Set<Room>`. The map is storing an object of type `Set<Room>`. Then in

```
io.of("/").adapter.sids.forEach(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + ' = ' + value)
})
```

`value` is a `Set<Room>`. Thats why you cannot add to `' = '`.

You can cycle over the `Set`. And in the set you have a `Room` object (with their own properties).